# Transparent background bug in dropdown panel with ng-select

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-ngselect

I have an odd bug that only occurs when the dropdown panel extends past the browser window. The background of the panel then becomes transparent. If the browser window is resized so that the dropdown panel can be completely visible upon clicking, the background is no longer transparent.

[image]

These are the custom styles affecting the ng-select dropdowns:

```css
    .prop-form {
      ...

      &__row {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: baseline;
      }

      &__col {
        flex: 1;
      }

      &__dropdown {
        display: flex;
        align-items: baseline;
      }

      &__ng-select {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0.75em 0.5em;
      }

      &__ng-select > .ng-value-container {
        padding-bottom: 0;
      }
    }
```

And the markup:

```html
    <div class="prop-form__row">
      ...
      <div class="prop-form__col">
        <div class="prop-form__dropdown">
          <ng-select class="prop-form__ng-select" name="time"
            [items]="scheduleFormService.timeOptions" [markFirst]="true" [clearable]="false" [searchable]="false"
            placeholder="Select time" formControlName="time">
            <ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item">
              <div>{{ item }}</div>
            </ng-template>
          </ng-select>
        </div>
      </div>
      ...
    </div>
```

Solutions already attempted (but did not work):

- Using `ViewEncapsulation.None` in the component and parent component
- Overriding default styles with `::ng-deep` in both the component and global styles

Bug occurs in Chrome and Safari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My coworker was able to find the problem. The height of the dropdown container was set to auto. So when the height of the modal isn't enough to display all of the items, the height adjusts to a smaller value.

Solution:

```css
.ng-dropdown-panel {
  white-space: normal;
  height: fit-content;
}
```